# How to project (draw) a rectangle on an incline plane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a bunch of points in 3D all on the same plane, having the general equation
$$
\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0\right)=0
$$
The unit normal is computed by using 3 points on the surface.

The best choice of system to investigate these points is the tangential frame of the plane. Therefore, I use the unit normal $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ for the first axes and compute the other two base vectors the following way:

For starters, an arbitrary vector not parallel to $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is needed. For the purpose I choose one of the usual 3D unit vectors $\hat{\mathbf{i}}=(1,0,0)$, $\hat{\mathbf{j}}=(0,1,0)$ or $\hat{\mathbf{k}}=(0,0,1)$. The choice is done based on the size of the angle $\hat{\mathbf{i}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}$,$\hat{\mathbf{j}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ or $\hat{\mathbf{k}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}$.  Using this, the other two base vectors of the tangential coordinate system are given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\mathbf{t}}_1 &= \hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\hat{\mathbf{i}}\\
\hat{\mathbf{t}}_2 &= \hat{\mathbf{n}}\times\hat{\mathbf{t}}_1
\end{aligned}
$$
Choosing one of the $\hat{\mathbf{i}},\hat{\mathbf{j}},\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ is supposed to prevent the random rotation around $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ of the vectors $\hat{\mathbf{t}}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf{t}}_2$(actually it is just a guess).

To transform between the frames following transformation matrix can be used.

$$
   \mathbf{R}=\left (
    \begin{matrix}
    \hat{\mathbf{i}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{t}}_1 & \hat{\mathbf{j}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{t}}_1 & \hat{\mathbf{k}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{t}}_1 \\
    \hat{\mathbf{i}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{t}}_2 & \hat{\mathbf{j}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{t}}_2 & \hat{\mathbf{k}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{t}}_2 \\
    \hat{\mathbf{i}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}   & \hat{\mathbf{j}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}   & \hat{\mathbf{k}}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} 
    \end{matrix}
   \right )
$$
This transformation matrix between the base vectors of the old and the new frame can be derived by noting that the vectors in the new frame $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$, $\hat{\mathbf{t}}_1$, $\hat{\mathbf{t}}_2$ can be expressed in terms of the vectors in the old frame $\hat{\mathbf{i}},\hat{\mathbf{j}},\hat{\mathbf{k}}$
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    \hat{\mathbf{t}}_1 = R_{11}\hat{\mathbf{i}} &+& R_{21}\hat{\mathbf{j}} &+& R_{31}\hat{\mathbf{k}} \\
    \hat{\mathbf{t}}_2 = R_{12}\hat{\mathbf{i}} &+& R_{22}\hat{\mathbf{j}} &+& R_{32}\hat{\mathbf{k}} \\
    \hat{\mathbf{n}}   = R_{13}\hat{\mathbf{i}} &+& R_{23}\hat{\mathbf{j}} &+& R_{33}\hat{\mathbf{k}} 
    \end{matrix}
$$

From the above the entries of the matrix can be found, for instance $R_{11}=\hat{\mathbf{i}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{t}}_1$

Subsequently, the coordinates of all points $P_i$ in the new frame can be computed by using the formula
$$
(\tilde{x}_i,\tilde{y}_i,\tilde{z}_i)=\mathbf{R}^{-1}\cdot(x_i,y_i,z_i)
$$

This can be derived by looking at the expansion of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ in the old base and the new base and comparing (Einstein summation is used). To keep the notation terse, lets use $\hat{\mathbf{e'}}_i$ for the new base and $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$  for the old.
$$
\mathbf{x}=x'^j\hat{\mathbf{e'}}_j=x'^iR^j_i\hat{\mathbf{e}}_j=x^j\hat{\mathbf{e}}_j
$$

Therefore, by comparing
$$
x'^iR^j_i=x^j.
$$

Where $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ is the inverse matrix. Since all points are on the same plane, the resulting set $(\tilde{x}_i,\tilde{y}_i,\tilde{z}_i)$ is in 2D.

Now I would like to do the following. Start with a rectangle located in the plane $z=0$ with $x\in(-1,1)$ and $y\in(-1,1)$ (not roated) and project it on the original plane defined by the unit vectors $\hat{\mathbf{t}}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf{t}}_2$ and $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$.

This should be done by computing $\mathbf{R}$ using the base vectors case of a non rotted rectangle
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\mathbf{i}} &= (1,0,0)\\
\hat{\mathbf{j}} &= (0,1,0)\\
\hat{\mathbf{k}} &= (0,0,1)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Unfortunately, the rectangle gets rotated when on the surface. Where I expect something like this:
[image]
I get:
[image: Case not ok]

**Question**

Therefore, I would like to ask the experts how to do this rotation. I basically need to figure out a way to "glue/ align" the rectangle with $\hat{\mathbf{i}},\hat{\mathbf{j}},\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ with the surface defined by $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$, $\hat{\mathbf{t}}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf{t}}_2$.

Running some trials, I noted that to get the desired transformation, I should use the inverse $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ to rotate $\hat{\mathbf{i}},\hat{\mathbf{j}},\hat{\mathbf{k}}$, which comes a bit surprising.

Comment: The equation $\hat n \cdot (\vec r-\vec r_0)=D$ where $\hat n$ is the unit normal of a plane and both $\vec r_0$ and $\vec r$ lie in the plane must have $D=0$.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to project the rectangle onto the plane, and then write the projection in the new coordinates.

If $\mathbf{p}$ is a point in $\Bbb{R}^3$, then the projection of $\mathbf{p}$ onto your plane $\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0)$ is [given by](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9605556/3558026)
$$\mathbf{q} = \mathbf{p} - (\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot (\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{r}_0))\hat{\mathbf{n}}.$$
So for for your rectangle $P= [-1,1]^2\times \{0\}$ the projection is
$$Q = \{\mathbf{p} - (\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot (\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{r}_0))\hat{\mathbf{n}} : \mathbf{p} \in [-1,1]^2\times \{0\}\}.$$
Now we have to write $\mathbf{q} \in Q$ in your new coordinates $(\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z})$ w.r.t. axes $\hat{\mathbf{n}}, \hat{\mathbf{t}}_1, \hat{\mathbf{t}}_2$. Since $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ corresponds to $(1,0,0)$, we have
$$(\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z}) = R^{-1}\mathbf{p} - (\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot (\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{r}_0),0,0).$$

Comment: thank you for the reply, is there a bracket missing in the last equation?

Comment: @AlexanderCska Rather, there was an extra bracket, thanks.

Comment: I thank you. Please give me some time to understand what you wrote and to try coding it.

Comment: To be sure, that we are on the same page, I would like to give a visual example. Imagine a cardboard with a bunch of points drawn on it. The simplest system to look at these points is spanned by the normal and 2 tangential vectors (in that frame one of the coordinates is the same for all points). Suppose I have a rectangle drawn on the cardboard and I have drawn a square on that cardboard (i use it to define the xy limits of a histogram). The million dollar question is how to go from the cardboard frame to the global $(1,0,0),(0,1,1),(0,0,1)$ with no rotating / distorting . Thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderCska If you project a $[-1,1]^2 \times \{0\}$ square onto a skew plane, there will certainly be rotating/distorting (and this is unrelated to the frame in which you're looking at it). Perhaps you are trying to define a square on the plane?